# how to enter words in synonyms.txt file of apache solr search

Tags: drupal-6, solr

I have configured the the apache solr search on my localhost.
I have read the synonyms.txt file, There i saw the Television, TV, TVs entered
So I created two pages with name of TV and Television and then search the TV
It give me two results TV and Television

Then enter two words test and tests in the synonyms.txt file just like Television and TV and Save the file.
Then I created two pages with the names test and tests.
When I search the test it only give me the result of test page and I was expected with two results of test and tests just like TV and Television.

So how to enter words in the synonyms.txt file and how to use it or configure it.
Any help?